# Unterminated string constant - javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In my `asp.net` application i am getting script error *UNTERMINATED STRING CONSTANT*. so i ensured the quotes are closed . yes its closed correctly . but am getting this error .

**NOTE :-** *am using IE . and this error displays at only sometimes*

```
<% if (Session[ "uname"]==null || Session[ "uname"].ToString()==string.Empty) { Session.Abandon(); %>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    alert('Page Expired!!!  Login Again. ');
    window.open('default.aspx', '_self');
  </script>

  <% return; } %>
```

Comment: You have space in `n ull `. Is this typo or same is written in page ?Also in `s tring`.

Comment: Is there a typo error or actual whitespace in `n ull` and  `s tring`

Comment: Apologies guys. That was issue with my edit.

Comment: ok, coming to the point . do u have any idea abt this @Rajesh

Comment: Please provide HTML/JavaScript only sample demonstrating the problem. Dev tools in browser of your choice should easily point you to line of script that fails - post that instead of some semi-random ASPX code (which very unlikely to produce error you observing).

Comment: am getting the error line in before the session.abandon (in brace) Note:my actual question was edited. so all things which i mentioned is now in one line @AlexeiLevenkov